# How do I keep my carpet edges from curling upwards?

Tags: carpet

A brand new rug that was put in under the coffee table has one corner that seems to keep lifting up and people keep stumbling on it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They make a product called [Rug-Gripper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001ZYYSI) that is specifically designed to hold a throw rug down.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what your rug is on - carpet or wood or stone floor. Also, how often you want to move it or remove it for cleaning.

I suspect the curl is a result of how the fibres in the weave are tightening. If that's the case, you could try soaking that corner and rolling it around a pipe of sorts in the opposite direction to how it curls, and let it dry or blow dry it. This might force the fibres to stretch in the direction you want.

If that fails, and provided it's on a solid floor, you could opt for double-sided carpet tape. The down side is that you'll have to apply it again every time you remove it for cleaning.

As a last option, if the rug is thick enough, you might be able to thread some wire into the edge of it around the corner and then bend the rug (and wire) flat.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that works best for me is a small piece of cardboard and either double sided tape or just staple the rug to the cardboard (not floor)